# My domain not redirect www to non- www

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, web

I am trying to redirect www (`www.mushko.com`) to non-www (`http://mushko.com/`) on my website but it's not working and it's showing this error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> www.mushko.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) check your DNS

2) you may be need added record DNS www IN CNAME domain.com.

3) send mail to support hosting.